# AS2 - terminate interval on main stage frame from movie clip on stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Hi,

I have an interval running within a function on the main stage, frame 1.  Where "foo" calls "bar" every 1ms using interval "timerCollapse" like so-

```
function foo() : Void {
var timerCollapse :Number= setInterval(bar, 1);
}

function bar() : Void {
trace("test");
}
```

Also tried using an undeclared method for the above like so-

```
timerCollapse = setInterval(bar, 1);
```

Then I have a clip on the stage that I would like to tell that interval to stop.  Below are the various methods tried but I cannot figure out how to stop the interval from another clip.

```
clearInterval(timerCollapse);       //does nothing
clearInterval(_root.timerCollapse); //does nothing
_root.clearInterval(timerCollapse); //does nothing
```

Any thoughts on how to kill that interval?

Many thanks :)

Comment: You have a scope issue, see a similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261977/how-does-one-break-out-of-a-set-interval-in-action-script-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to do somethign like the following:

framescript:

```
var myInterval;

function startMyInterval() {
    myInterval = setInterval(update, 1000);
}

function update() {
    trace('hi');
}
```

button in a movie clip

```
on(release) {
    clearInterval(_root.myInterval);
}
```

call *startMyInterval* from wherever.

Comment: @cheeseomelete (great handle btw) did you get the above integrated successfully?

Comment: hah thanks, all the good names were taken :)  I adapted the button code you have there to do it directly when it hit that specific frame and that did it!  Thanks!

Comment: also by declaring the interval ID properly as you have here so it knew what to clobber.